# Content of frames disappears when using slide notes in a rmarkdown::beamer_presentation

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, markdown, beamer

I generate a `LaTex beamer presentation` with `rmarkdown::beamer_presentation`.
When I use slide notes by adding `header-includes: \setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}` to the YAML header, *a lot of content of the presentation disappears*:
LaTex math, words, tables,

Please see the images below. As can be seen from the second screenshot, the content is "still there", it's just printed in white somehow (for no straightforward reason, see the simple MWE below).

### Frames with & Without Slide Notes

[image: MWE_noSlideNotes-withSlideNotes]

### Frames with Slide Notes: Screenshot to show content "is there" (hidden/in white)

[image: withSlideNotes and highlight]

### MWE

````
---
title: "Slide notes in an rmarkdown::beamer_presentation"
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    base_format: rmarkdown::beamer_presentation
    latex_engine: xelatex
    toc: false
    slide_level: 2
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{hyperref}
  - \setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}
---

## table
<!-- ======================================================== -->
\label{FRAME-table-cars}

```{r table, cars, echo = FALSE}
library(kableExtra)
knitr::kable(head(mtcars[, 1:3]), caption = "Table caption")
```
<!-- LaTex label: -->
\captionof{table}{foo}
\label{foo}

\begin{center}
\begin{tiny} 
($\Rightarrow$ See also: \hyperlink{FRAME-plot-pressure}{pressure plot} \hyperlink{FRAME-other-1}{other 1})\linebreak
($\Rightarrow$ and further: \hyperlink{FRAME-other-2}{other 2} \hyperlink{FRAME-other-3}{other 3})
\end{tiny} 
\end{center}

\note{
\textbf{Note frame 1}\\
1 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\\
2 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXA\\
3 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXAB\\
4 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXABC\\
}

## Plot
<!-- ======================================================== -->
\label{FRAME-plot-pressure}

```{r plot, echo=FALSE, out.width='66%'}
plot(pressure)
```
<!-- LaTex label: -->
\captionof{figure}{bar}
\label{bar}

\begin{center}
\begin{tiny} 
($\Rightarrow$ See also: \hyperlink{FRAME-table-cars}{table cars} \hyperlink{FRAME-other-1}{other 1})\linebreak
($\Rightarrow$ and further: \hyperlink{FRAME-other-2}{other 2} \hyperlink{FRAME-other-3}{other 3})
\end{tiny} 
\end{center}

\note{
\textbf{Note frame 2}\\
1 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\\
2 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXA\\
3 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXAB\\
4 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXABC\\
}

## Other frame 1
<!-- ======================================================== -->
\label{FRAME-other-1}

## Other frame 2
<!-- ======================================================== -->
\label{FRAME-other-2}

## Other frame 3
<!-- ======================================================== -->
\label{FRAME-other-3}
````

Uncomment `header-includes: \setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}` to include the slide notes --  whereby the table, the arrows, and the hyperrefs below the figure/table will disappear.

Comment: that is a bug with pgf/xelatex, use another engine to avoid the problem.

Comment: ... and don't load the `hyperref` package, beamer already does that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a problem with old xelatex versions, just use another engine to avoid the problem.

If you really need xelatex for some reason, you can upgrade to the texlive 2021 pretest, there the problem is solved.

````
---
title: "Slide notes in an rmarkdown::beamer_presentation"
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    base_format: rmarkdown::beamer_presentation
    latex_engine: lualatex
    toc: false
    slide_level: 2
header-includes:
  - \setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}
---

## table
<!-- ======================================================== -->
\label{FRAME-table-cars}

```{r table, cars, echo = FALSE}
library(kableExtra)
knitr::kable(head(mtcars[, 1:3]), caption = "Table caption")
```
<!-- LaTex label: -->
\captionof{table}{foo}
\label{foo}

\begin{center}
\begin{tiny} 
($\Rightarrow$ See also: \hyperlink{FRAME-plot-pressure}{pressure plot} \hyperlink{FRAME-other-1}{other 1})\linebreak
($\Rightarrow$ and further: \hyperlink{FRAME-other-2}{other 2} \hyperlink{FRAME-other-3}{other 3})
\end{tiny} 
\end{center}

\note{
\textbf{Note frame 1}\\
1 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\\
2 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXA\\
3 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXAB\\
4 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXABC\\
}

## Plot
<!-- ======================================================== -->
\label{FRAME-plot-pressure}

```{r plot, echo=FALSE, out.width='66%'}
plot(pressure)
```
<!-- LaTex label: -->
\captionof{figure}{bar}
\label{bar}

\begin{center}
\begin{tiny} 
($\Rightarrow$ See also: \hyperlink{FRAME-table-cars}{table cars} \hyperlink{FRAME-other-1}{other 1})\linebreak
($\Rightarrow$ and further: \hyperlink{FRAME-other-2}{other 2} \hyperlink{FRAME-other-3}{other 3})
\end{tiny} 
\end{center}

\note{
\textbf{Note frame 2}\\
1 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\\
2 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXA\\
3 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXAB\\
4 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXABC\\
}

## Other frame 1
<!-- ======================================================== -->
\label{FRAME-other-1}

## Other frame 2
<!-- ======================================================== -->
\label{FRAME-other-2}

## Other frame 3
<!-- ======================================================== -->
\label{FRAME-other-3}
````

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick and elegant solution!

Comment: For anyone stumbling upon a similar issue and yet cannot compile with `lualatex`: I had to make sure that my presenter notes did not contain any special characters or citations

Comment: any idea what `LuaTex`would like me to do? `Package fontspec Warning: Input mapping not supported in LuaTeX. (fontspec) Use "Ligatures=TeX" instead of "Mapping=tex-text".`

Comment: @mavericks not without seeing a [mre]

Comment: will try to cook up an MWE